# How can I "reconstruct" the background of an image with Python?

Tags: python

How can I "reconstruct" the background of an image with Python? I mean, if there are several objects in front of the same background, how can I isolate that background using those images to like "take the objects away" from it?

The description of my project is:
"There's a way to rescue the background image from a photo. For example, retrieve the backdrop where a person is walking. This is achieved by analyzing several photos that share the same background. Once these pictures are analyzed, you can delete the image that keeps the background image to be shown. This project aims to build a program that reads a finite set of images (in PPM format) and then analyzes the images in order to obtain the background image."

Does anyone know if this has a specific name to investigate? Does anyone have any information about this?

Answer (score 0):

While generally on Stack Overflow you shouldn't ask for software recommendations, I had a similar problem recently and I know how hard it is to find a Python *anything* that fits a specific need in this area.

You may be interested in a library called [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/).

With this library it is possible to do advanced image editing, including reconstructing backgrounds. An example of the power of `SimpleCV` is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/m68js/trying_to_write_a_very_simple_green_screen_code/) Reddit post detailing a problem with greenscreens that was solved with `SimpleCV`.

Hope this helps!

Best of luck, and happy coding!